# ¿Cómo hacer correctamente un JComboBox?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy experimentando con los componentes *Swing* de *Java*, mi problema es que me arroja una advertencia al crear un **JComboBox**, este componente lo creo de la siguiente manera:

```
// Creación del ComboBox
String opciones[] = {"Círculo", "Cuadrado"};
JComboBox forma = new JComboBox(opciones);
```

Y me da la siguiente advertencia:

```
warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: JComboBox
JComboBox forma = new JComboBox(opciones);
                      ^
missing type arguments for generic class JComboBox<E>
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class JComboBox

warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to JComboBox(E[]) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
JComboBox forma = new JComboBox(opciones);
                  ^
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
```

**¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo o qué error cometo en su declaración?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice un código muy corto y simple con unos comentarios de guia.

La primera parte que será unas pocas lineas, agregando un String[] al JComboBox, y la segunda un poco más larga agregando un ArrayList, va como anexo nomás.

Si podés copiá y pegá ése código en una clase que se llame "Panel" y luego "Run as java application" y probá seleccionado los combobox y qué dice por consola.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel {

    private ArrayList<String> paisesArrayList;
    private JComboBox<String> comboArray, comboArrayList;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Panel() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setTitle("JComboBox");

        /* Directamente con un Array */
        String[] paisesArray = new String[] { "Argentina", "Brasil", "Ecuador" };
        comboArray = new JComboBox<String>(paisesArray);
        panel.add(comboArray);
        /* Probamos el seleccionador por la consola */
        comboArray.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println(comboArray.getSelectedItem()));

        /* Directamente desde un ArrayList<String>, pasamos el ArrayList a un array */
        paisesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        paisesArrayList.add("Argentina");
        paisesArrayList.add("Chile");
        paisesArrayList.add("Uruguay");
        /*
         * Una vez creado y cargado el AL, utilizamos toArray() para pasarlo a array
         * comun y le decimos que el array tiene que tener el tamño exacto que cantidad
         * de objetos que tiene el AL
         */
        comboArrayList = new JComboBox<String>(paisesArrayList.toArray(new String[paisesArrayList.size()]));
        panel.add(comboArrayList);
        /* Probamos el seleccionador por la consola */
        comboArrayList.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println(comboArrayList.getSelectedItem()));

        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();

    }

}
```

Igualmente lo que no entiendo es si éstas dos lineas te tiran error de compilación o sólo una **advertencia**.

```
        String opciones[] = {"Círculo", "Cuadrado"};
        JComboBox forma = new JComboBox(opciones);
```

Digo esto porque el tema es así, vos podés declarar un JComboBox en la clase sin parametrizar, ejemplo:

```
private JComboBox combo;
```

Sin embargo a tu izquiera **te va a aparecer una advertencia** comentando que ése **JComboBox debería estar parametrizado**, qué pasa si no lo parametrizás? **la jdk le asigna un parámetro de la clase Object**.

así como **tampoco deberías tener problema de crear el JComboBox sin parametrizar**, también te va a tirar otra **advertencia**.

```
comboArray = new JComboBox(paisesArray);
```

Fijate que no está parametrizado y tampoco tira error, ya que **la jdk le asigna el de** .

**En conclusión la jdk espera a que vos le indiques qué tipo de Objecto vas a ingresar a ese JComboBox.**

Ahora te dejo un último ejemplito:

```
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Panel {

        private JFrame frame;
        private JPanel panel;

        public Panel() {


            Integer opciones[] = {1, 2};
            JComboBox forma = new JComboBox(opciones);
            frame = new JFrame();
            panel = new JPanel();

            frame.add(panel);
            panel.add(forma);
            frame.setTitle("JComboBox");

            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 250);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }

        /* Método inicializador de App */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
            Panel p = new Panel();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea te da la clave de lo que te pasa:

```
missing type arguments for generic class JComboBox<E>
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
```

Te dice que JComboBox es una clase genérica a la que no le has pasado el argumento .

En tu caso le vas a pasar Strings, con lo cual en vez de E tienes que indicar que le pasas un String[]:

```
JComboBox<String[]> forma = new JComboBox<String[]>(forma);.
```

No estoy seguro de que se haga exactamente así pero el fallo que te indica es ese.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, lo intenté como dijiste y me arroja un error de que no se encuentra el constructor para ese componente **(JComboBox<String[]>)**.

Comment: ponlo sin los [] a ver que pasa

Comment: Igual lo mismo, los tipos no coinciden según la consola, lo arreglé de otra manera:

Comment: Primero creo el componente: `JComboBox<String> forma = new JComboBox<String>();`, seguidamente con el método `JComboBox.addItem(String);` agrego todos los elementos que necesito (uno por uno) y finalmente con `JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(int);` indico cual elemento es el que está seleccionado. Es la única manera en que logro que no me arroje advertencia.

Comment: pues así, creo que es la forma correcta de hacerlo, yo pretend´ñia cargar el combo de un viaje pero de uno en uno no está mal